# ngFor click only one item

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a problem with the ngFor: for each item in the list I have an image and by clicking I would like to show the details of only that image. The problem is that if I click on an image, the details of all the items in the list come out.

.html:

```
  <div class=" gif" *ngFor="let r of result">
    <img [src]="r.images.downsized.url" alt="image" (click)="getDetails()">
    <div class="v3" *ngIf="this.clicked">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>
            <h2>username: {{r?.username}}</h2>
            <h3>title: {{r?.title}}</h3>
            <p>import date:{{r?.import_datetime}}</p>
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </div>
  </div>
```

.ts:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.clicked = false
  }

  getDetails(): void {
    if (!this.clicked) {
      this.clicked = true
    }
    else {
      this.clicked = false
    }
  }
```

Comment: use the variable you use in the loop : `(click)="getDetails(r)"` and in your function, e.g.: `getDetails(el:any){console.log(el)}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` in your case is component instance, so `this.clicked` is global for all your iterated items, that is why all of them get shown. As one solution you can store clicked index:

```
<div class="gif" *ngFor="let r of result; let i = index">
  <img [src]="r.images.downsized.url" alt="image" (click)="clickedIndex = i">
  <div class="v3" *ngIf="clickedIndex === i">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>
          <h2>username: {{r?.username}}</h2>
          <h3>title: {{r?.title}}</h3>
          <p>import date:{{r?.import_datetime}}</p>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another solution would be to move details section from the loop into separate component, which will receive details as @Input

Comment: you can pass the "r" directly

Comment: sure we can, if I understand you correctly save current iteration object, let's say `clickedImage` and then check if it is the same instance: `*ngIf="clickedImage === r"`

Comment: is there a simple way to make it so that if you click again on the image, the details shown in the first click disappear?

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer,  if you want to toggle image details, return your `getDetails()` function and send current index into it: `(click)="getDetails(i)"`, and inside this function just check if the index is the same as selected index and reset it if so, something like: `this.clickedIndex = this.clickedIndex === i ? undefined : i`

Comment: perfect, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The `this` refers to the whole component. Alas there is only one `this.clicked`.

Change `(click)="getDetails()"` to something like `(click)="getDetails(r)"` and
`getDetails(): void {` to something like `getDetails(r: TypeOfR): void {` and keep an array or hashmap with clicked Rs.